# Перегрузка функций и область видимости

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Исходный пример:

```
#include <ostream>

template<typename T>
void serialize(std::ostream& stream, const T& value) {}

template<typename T>
class Field
{
public:
    void serialize(std::ostream& stream)
    {
        serialize(stream, m_value);
    }

protected:
    T m_value = {};
};
```

Пример кода не компилируется (gcc-9, std=c++2a). Однако вывод компилятора подсказывает, что функция `serialize(std::ostream&, const T&)` недоступна для вызова из данного контекста. Меняем тело метода `serialize` на следующий код:

```
::serialize(stream, m_value);
```

Все работает. Однако, для меня неочевидно, почему возникают такие проблемы - функции, имеющие разные сигнатуры, *внезапно* создают коллизии. Дайте ссылку на конкретный параграф стандарта.

P.S. Проверил с non-template классом - ситуация аналогичная.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сразу надо заметить, что немедленной ошибки в приведенном вами коде нет, ибо приведенный *шаблонный* код не инстанцирован и name lookup для него сразу не выполняется, ибо внутренний вызов `serialize` зависит от шаблонного параметра `T`. И при конкретном инстанцировании результаты процесса name lookup для имени `serailize` теоретически могут зависеть и от конкретного типа `T` (см. ниже), и от того места, в котором выполнено инстанцирование. В вашем примере ничего этого не приведено.

Но с общей точки зрения вы наблюдаете классический name hiding. Любое имя во вложенной области видимости скрывает **все** имена из охватывающих областей видимости.

В явном виде это явление в стандарте не описано (или может даже описано, как вы сами сказали в `[basic.scope.hiding]`), но в любом случае оно вытекает напрямую из того факта, что name lookup и overload resolution - два отдельных этапа в С++. Сначала делается unqualified name lookup, который традиционно выполняет поиск изнутри-наружу снизу-вверх и *останавливается* на той области видимости, к которой найдено хотя бы одно подходящее имя. Затем запускается процесс overload resolution только для имен, найденных именно в этой области видимости.

---

Тут можно было бы понадеяться на argument-dependent lookup (ADL), который при правильном типе аргумента `m_value` мог бы увидеть и глобальное объявление `serialize`. Однако стандарт явно говорит, что если *обычный* name lookup нашел в качестве кандидата *имя члена класса,* то ADL тут же игнорируется (http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#3.1). Поэтому в вашем случае ADL не помогает.

В нижеприведенном же примере тоже имеет место name hiding, но сокрытие выполняется не методом класса, а внешней функцией

```
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

struct S {};

template<typename T>
void serialize(std::ostream& stream, const T& value) {}

namespace X {
  void serialize(std::ostream& stream) {}

  template<typename T>
  class Field
  {
  public:
    void foo(std::ostream& stream)
    {
      serialize(stream, m_value);
    }

  protected:
    T m_value = {};
  };
}

int main()
{
  X::Field<int> f1;
  f1.foo(std::cout); // <- ошибка 

  X::Field<S> f2;
  f2.foo(std::cout); // <- все в порядке
}
```

В таком варианте ADL не игнорируется. В этом примере при `T == int` ADL ничего не находит и мы получаем ту же самую ошибку по той же самой причине, что и в вашем примере. А вот при `T == S` ADL позволяет нам найти еще и глобальную `serialize` и ошибка пропадет.

Comment: Спасибо, Ant! Параграф сам нашел - http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.hiding :)

Comment: За пример с ADL - отдельное спасибо :)

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: С чего бы это вдруг? Если функция, которая имеет доступ к защищенному члену, передаст ссылку на него кому угодно, этот "кто угодно" тоже получит доступ к этому защищенному члену.

Comment: @AnT,  но данная функция_член не передает ссыльку на защищенный член, она в аргументе имеет лишь  std::ostream&

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Она передает ссылку на защищенный член во *внешнюю* функцию.

Comment: @AnT, признаю, я был не прав