# С++, странная ситуация со вложенными пространствами имен

Tags: c++, namespace

Никак не могу понять, почему следующий код выводит `3`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo(int i)
{ 
    cout << 1 << endl; 
}

namespace A 
{
    void foo(char k) 
    { 
        cout << 2 << endl; 
    }
    namespace B 
    {
        void foo(double j) 
        { 
            cout << 3 << endl;
        }
        namespace C 
        {
            void bar() 
            { 
                foo(1); 
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    A::B::C::bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Буду очень признателен, если кто-нибудь поможет в этом разобраться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Имеет место обыкновенное сокрытие имен. Вопрос фактически является вариацией

[Перегрузка функций и область видимости](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/993763/182825)

Любое имя во вложенной области видимости скрывает все имена из охватывающих областей видимости. Для вызова `foo(1)` сначала делается *поиск неквалифицированного имени* (unqualified name lookup) для имени `foo`, который выполняетcя изнутри-наружу снизу-вверх и останавливается на той области видимости, к которой найдено хотя бы одно имя `foo`. Затем запускается процесс overload resolution только для имен, найденных именно в этой области видимости. А это только `foo(double)`.

Увидеть скрытые имена может только ADL, но в вашем примере он не помогает. Если вы каким-то образом (при помощи ADL) заставите процесс поиска имен рассмотреть и глобальное пространство имен тоже, то вызовется `foo` именно из глобального пространства имен.

Например, если бы у вашей функции был еще один параметр класс- или enum-типа из глобального пространства имен, то вызывалась бы именно `int` версия вашей функции

```
enum E { X };

void foo(int i, E e)
{ 
  cout << 1 << endl; 
}

namespace A 
{
  void foo(char k, E e) 
  { 
    cout << 2 << endl; 
  }
  namespace B 
  {
    void foo(double j, E e) 
    { 
      cout << 3 << endl;
    }
    namespace C 
    {
      void bar() 
      { 
        foo(1, X);   // вызывается `::foo`
        foo(1.0, X); // вызывается `A::B::foo`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что и в этом случае вызов `foo('a', X)` вызовет `::foo`, а не `A::foo`. ADL привнес в рассмотрение глобальное пространство имен, а пространство `A` никто в рассмотрение не привносил.

Answer (score 1):

foo, которое выводит 1 находится в глобальном пространстве имён, а в bar вы обращаетесь к другой foo, которая находится в том же пространстве имен, что и C::bar. Если хотите увидеть 1, то обращайтесь ::foo.